# Returning new collection instead of existing collection instance variable

Tags: java

I was having trouble understanding the following snippet:

```
public class Person {
   private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

   public List<Person> getPeople() {
      return new ArrayList<Person>();
   }
}
```

Edit: Sorry, maybe I got my terms incorrect. I guess I've seen code like this where a new collection is returned, and there is a collection instance variable for that class.  So I was wondering what the implications were.

Comment: The question requires clarification. What do you mean by 'anonymous' in this context? I can't see it.

Answer (score 7):

That's not an anonymous class, it's just an empty list.

I realised you *might* be talking about returning a new object that hasn't been assigned to a named variable, and so is anonymous in that sense. The example you give looks like it could be improved - it seems that `getPeople()` should return the `people` variable, since that's already been initialised to an empty `List` and using that would save the overhead of creating a fresh empty list on each call to `getPeople()`.

Now that you've edited your question, I think the above is probably what you were asking.

Answer (score 6):

This may represent an example of [*coding to the interface*](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1999/jw-08-interfaces.html). In the example, `ArrayList` is an implementation detail. Returning `List` indicates that clients should only rely on `List` methods of the returned object.

Comment: This is probably what the OP was talking about - just using the wrong term.

Answer (score 5):

This is returning an anonymous List :

```
public class Person {
   public List<Person> getPeople() {
      return new ArrayList<Person>(){};
   }
}
```

To be exact, it's an anonymous ArrayList.

An anonymous List would be :

```
public class Person {
   public List<Person> getPeople() {
      return new List<Person>(){
          //implementing all methods required for a List.
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: To be even more exact, it is an anonymous **subclass of** `ArrayList`.